# Xubuntu 16.04 -> 18.04 media keys don't work, brightness keys are very laggy to enable

Tags: sound, keyboard, xubuntu, shortcut-keys, brightness

There are other posts on this, but nothing seems to help.

Before when changing volume with media keys, you would see a little overlay (in the color you select in your theme) that shows the adjusted volume.

Brightness keys also had this.

Now in 18.04 upgrade for xubuntu, volume media keys just don't work, and brightness keys are extremely laggy.

Is this as known bug, or what are possible solutions to this?

My only guess is programs used to do this are disabled, or the polling for these events is extremely delayed, or configs changed.

Any help would be appreciated!

EDIT: It appears media keys work, but as brightness, it takes many many seconds to pass before they're recognized, and no overlay image that shows the progress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem seemed to be that `xfce4-notifyd` was disabled (can see settings in `xfce4-notifyd-config`).

To check status one can do: `systemctl --user status xfce4-notifyd`

The solution being to start it: `systemctl --user start xfce4-notifyd`

I do not know if this enables it on startup, but that shouldn't difficult to add to dbus services.

With this enabled, the overlay progress bars return, and the ability to change brightness or volume at will has returned.